# How can I capture HttpErrorResponse status and display it in angular component

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an angular project back end with node.js, how can I call and get httpErrorResponse status or headers to display in my components page when my server is down or not responding.

here is my component function code:

```
 UpdateData(){

    this.newServices.updateNews(result, result.id).subscribe(
    (res)=>{
         console.log(res)
    }),
    (error)=>{
      console.log(error)
    }
 }
```

my service.ts function:

```
    updateNews(data, id) {
    try {
     return this.http.post(this.baseurl + "/news/update/" + id, data)
    } catch (err) {
      this.handleError(err);
    }
   }
```

how can I check in my component the http responses so that I can display messages on the browser

Comment: in the `(error) => ` callback you can read out the [error object](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse) and take according action.

Comment: Could you please provide an example because I can get status code when server is up but I can't get when server is down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally its not advisable to show the error message to the user that returned from server. For example the error may be: Cant reach the xx.xx.xx due to CORS policy. So if u show this the user cant understand whats happening. So its advisable to use a toaster Service to show error to user.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr

```
getPlayersList() {
    this.playerService.getPlayersList().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.playersData = res.data;
    }, err => {
      this.toasterService.showFailure('Sorry something went wrong');
    })
  }
```

In some scenarios if u want to show the error thats coming from api like 500 response u can do in this way

```
getPlayersList() {
    this.playerService.getPlayersList().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.playersData = res.data;
    }, err => {
      this.toasterService.showFailure(err.err.message);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your service:

```
    updateNews(data, id) {
 return this.http.post(this.baseurl + "/news/update/" + id, data)
```

}

In your function:

```
this.newServices.updateNews(result, result.id).subscribe(
(res)=>{
     console.log(res)
}),
(error)=>{
  console.log(error)
}
```